# MatDialog is undefined in entry component

Tags: angular, typescript

I use the latest Angular version and I modify a template. I have a module called `toolbar.module.ts` which contains an `entryComponent`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ToolbarComponent, ToolbarDropdownComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    [...]
  ],
  exports: [ToolbarComponent],
  entryComponents: [ToolbarDropdownComponent]
})
export class ToolbarModule {
}
```

Inside `ToolbarDropdownComponent` I use it as following:

```
[...]
export class ToolbarDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  foo() {
     this.dialog.open(...); <--- this.dialog is undefined
  }
}
```

I use it in the same way I use `MatDialog` anywhere else. Is there something different here? What could `this.dialog` causing being undefined? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's public. Make it private and you can use `this`.

Comment: I use `this` and private or public shouldn't make a difference: Edit: confirmed, unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: can you add import section of `MatDialog` in you component file.
Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvfr7z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
export class ToolbarDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  foo() {
     this.dialog.open(...); 
  }
}
```